# Rails 3 - Couldn't find Photo with ID=quick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view

I created new model via scaffold and I added new action there - **quick**. To **routes.rb** I added **get "photos/quick"** and created the file **qucik.html.erb** (and it's in the right view-directory).

If I will set to browser **localhost:3000/photos/quick**, I will get the error above.
In my controller it looks very simple:

```
def quick
end
```

And also in the view:

```
<div>this is template for quick action</div>
```

How is possible to get that error message? Why is run **show** action?

**routes.rb:**

```
FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :photos
  get "photos/quick"

   root :to => "photos#index"

end
```

Comment: Show your relevant `routes.rb` contents for the `photos`.

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not in an external site.

Comment: I've added your code into your question, but please remember to make the question as complete as possible on SO's site instead of linking to external sites..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change routes to use `collection` and fix the code structure to use the blocks properly:

```
FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do    
  resources :photos do
    collection do
      get "quick"
    end
  end
  root :to => "photos#index"
end
```

See some [documentation here about such routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: I edited my code by your hint, but still the same. I tried to restart WEBrick, but again the same.

Comment: Oop. Changed the answer above to use `collection` instead of `member`

Comment: Now I got interesting think - if I will set to browser `localhost:3000/photos/quickkkkkkkkk`, so I will get the same error as is in the title of this topic... I don't get error about bad routing